# Declare String List Variable in .yml and pass to Script as argument

Tags: c#, azure, yaml, devops

1. I have a list of strings.
2. I want to declare them in the variable section in the .yml file
3. I want to pass the list variable to multiple - task: PowerShell@2

Here is my.yaml:

```
# my pipelinename:
$(RunName)$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)
trigger:
- main
pool:
name: default
variables:
RunName: 'my-runname'
ProjectName: '**/my.csproj'
Configuration: 'Debug'
MyList:  ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']

stages:
- stage: RunTests  
displayName: 'RunTests'  
jobs:  
- job: RunTests    
displayName: 'RunTests'    
steps:

- task: PowerShell@2      
displayName: 'MyName'      
continueOnError: true      
inputs:        
filePath: 'my/script-that-accepts-my-list.ps1'        
arguments:                    
-MyList $(MyList)       
workingDirectory: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/my-project/"
```

1. Is there a way to declare a list of strings in the variables: section in my.yml file, if yes, please advise?
2. Is there an alternative way to do it?

Thank you very much!

I tried declaring the list like so:

```
MyList:  ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']
```

and so:

```
MyList:  
 - item1
 - item2
 - item3
 - item4
 - item5
 - item6
```

and so:

```
MyList: 
 item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6
```

Most of the time I get the error:
my.yml (Line: Where list id declared): A sequence was not expected

I execute a .yml pipeline on a local Azure DevOps server agent. And this is where I get the error.

**I know I can do this and it will work:**

```
arguments:
-MyList @('item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3', 'item_4', 'item_5', 'item_6')
```

But this way I cannot reuse the list, and I have 2 scripts I want to pass it to.

To summarize and make it even more explicit:

1. I want to extract the list of items in a variable
2. Pass that var into multiple script tasks (- task: PowerShell@2) as argument.

Thank you!
Regards!

Comment: The [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format looks completely different from the [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) format. The officially recommended file extension for files containing YAML documents has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried this and it looks like it worked:

Declared the variable like so:

```
variables:
MyList: "@('item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3', 'item_4', 'item_5', 'item_6')"
```

And then used it like so:

```
arguments:
-MyList $(MyList)
```

And the script printed the list.

This is how my script.ps1 looks like:

```
param($MyList = @())
Write-Host "This Is My List: $MyList "

foreach($item in $MyList) {
Write-Host "This Item From My List: $item"
}
```

So it seems to be working.

Although if there are more solutions I am eager to learn them.

Thank you!